# using regex on dynamique mapping elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I was wondering if my template mapping is correct using regex on ES 5.5. I need to filter all fields containing a certain regex and not index them

Fileds look like:

> attributes.imageLink@Media_link
>
> attributes.gtinLinks@PimStd_link

and my template mapping contains the ES match regex:

```
{
                    link: {
                        path_match: 'attributes.*_link',
                        mapping: {
                            type: 'keyword',
                            index: 'analyzed',
                            copy_to: ['references', 'keyword'],
                        },
                    },
                },
                {
                    otherLink: {
                        match_pattern: 'regex',
                        match: 'gtinLinks|imageLink',
                        mapping: {
                            type: 'keyword',
                            index: 'no',
                        },
                    },
                },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mapping was finally correct, the mapping

```
                    match_pattern: 'regex',
                    match: 'gtinLinks|imageLink',
```

Does filter the all fields containing *gtinLinks|imageLink*

I was able to see that using the _analyze API and doing some pattern match on text